# I have an offset when using material ui table, what's the problem?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, offset

I have a problem using material ui table, everytime I have this weird behavior and don't know how to fix it, tried many solutions and styling the cells but never fixed.

I've noticed that this often happens when I add data to display in my table.

Thanks

[this is what i have when adding values in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPNid.png)

This is a part of my code

```html
<TableBody>
          <StyledTableRow>
            <TableCellTitle />
            {renderYears1()
              .slice(0, 1)
              .map((year) =>
                year.map((y) => (
                  <StyledTableCell>
                    {y.map((yr) => (
                      <StyledTableCellStrong>{yr}</StyledTableCellStrong>
                    ))}
                  </StyledTableCell>
                ))
              )}
          </StyledTableRow>
          {dataTestingObj.map((data) => (
            <StyledTableRow>
              <TableCellTitle>{data.company}</TableCellTitle>
              {Object.values(data)
                .slice(0, 5)
                .map((val) => (
                  <StyledTableCell>
                    {Object.values(val.values).map((vl) => (
                      <StyledTableCell>
                        {parseFloat(vl).toFixed(2)}
                      </StyledTableCell>
                    ))}
                  </StyledTableCell>
                ))}
            </StyledTableRow>
          ))}
          <StyledTableRowStrong>
            <TableCellTitleStrong>Total Average</TableCellTitleStrong>    
              {arrayByMetrics.length > 0 &&
                arrayByMetrics.map((val) => (
                <StyledTableCell>
                  <StyledTableCellStrong>
                    {parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)}%
                  </StyledTableCellStrong>
                </StyledTableCell>
                ))}     
          </StyledTableRowStrong>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCellTitle>Issuer</TableCellTitle>
            <StyledTableCell>
              {revenueCagr[4].map((val) => (
                <StyledTableCell>{parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              ))}
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell>
              {revenueGrowth[4].map((val) => (
                <StyledTableCell>{parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              ))}
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell>
              {grossMargin[4].map((val) => (
                <StyledTableCell>{parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              ))}
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell>
              {ebitdaMargin[4].map((val) => (
                <StyledTableCell>{parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              ))}
            </StyledTableCell>
            <StyledTableCell>
              {ebitaMargin[4].map((val) => (
                <StyledTableCell>{parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)}</StyledTableCell>
              ))}
            </StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
```

Comment: Can you add reproducible code [here](https://react.new/)

Comment: it looks like the data you are iterating isn't consistently formatted. try to `console.log({ebitdaMargin)}` to see what inside isn't formatted correctly.